# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am picking up two dates from a DateTimePicker in a Winforms app and running a SQL query against the two dates and saving the output in an Excel. I am using the below code. It's throwing an exception

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Please assist to fix this issue

```
DateTime startdate = dPStartDate.Value;
DateTime enddate = dPEndDate.Value;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;

string query = "Select Incident_Number from HELP_DESK where Assigned_Group = 'Compliance' and Submit_Date between @startdate and @enddate";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);

conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

ds.WriteXml(@"c:/File_Name.XLS");

conn.Close();
```

Comment: What is the type of `Submit_Date` in the database?

Comment: The datatype of Submit_Date in database is datetime

Comment: What's the values of `startdate` and `enddate`?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: While `AddWithValue` is problematic in some cases, it will be able to infer the right type for a `DateTime` value just fine so that's not it.

Comment: startdate is "01/07/2015 00:00:00" and enddate is "31/07/2015 00:00:00"

Comment: Is `HELP_DESK` a view or a table? If a view, can you check the expression and underlying column for the `Submit_Date` column?

Comment: Thanks. Let me verify this ...

Comment: You are right. The HELP_Desk is a view. I changed the table to the actual table and it worked